# Setting screen size in PhantomJS C# being driven by Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs

How do I set the browser screen size? When I take a screen shot after setting up PhantomJS as below its only showing a 400px wide image.

```
var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
driverService.LoadImages = false;
driverService.ProxyType = "none";      

using (var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService))
{
    etc....
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be the same as setting window size in any other browsers, feel free to have a look at this example: [How to get window size, resize or maximize window using Selenium WebDriver](http://yizeng.me/2014/02/23/how-to-get-window-size-resize-or-maximize-window-using-selenium-webdriver/#c-sharp-example).

Here is the code tested working for me:

```
var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
driverService.LoadImages = false;
driverService.ProxyType = "none";

using (var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService)) {
    driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1920, 1080); // Size is a type in assembly "System.Drawing"
    driver.Url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
    driver.TakeScreenshot().SaveAsFile(@"c:\phantomjs_screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Comment: `TakeScreenshot` method has been changed to `GetScreenshot` in a later version